# Data cleaning of (lat,long) coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, geospatial, latitude-longitude

I'm new to Python and I want to understand how I can remove values from my dataset that are 0.00000
In context, I am working on the dataset https://www.kaggle.com/ksuchris2000/oklahoma-earthquakes-and-saltwater-injection-wells

The file InjectionWells.csv has some values in their coordinates (LAT and LONG) which I need to remove but I don't know exactly how. This is so I can make a scatterplot with X longitude and Y latitude

I tried the following but didn't work. Can you please guide me?

Comment: Don't say something vague like *"the dataset has some (LAT and LONG) values which I need to remove but I don't know exactly how"*; from the plot, do you want to remove `dat['LONG']  >= -75`? or `dat['LAT'] > 30`? or both? Be specific. Use [`dat.describe()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) to see the descriptive statistics on each (numeric) column, then you know what the outlier values are.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant that I want to remove, not only from the plot but for the dataset for further analysis the following: dat['LAT']<=30, >=40 and dat['LONG'] <=-108 >=-90

Comment: Well if you knew the answer, but didn't post it in the question... that's just wasted 20min of my work on my answer showing you how to programmatically detect the outliers and exclude them. Anyway my answer also shows you how to include/exclude a range of (LAT,LONG) with an `.apply()` function.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation but I even mentioned in the first line of my question that I wanted to understand how to delete values that are 0.0000 (as an example). Basically, I knew which values I needed to delete because I put the database in an Excel file so I had an idea with filters what was weird. Still, as I am new to Python I just didn't know how to delete certain rows from those columns in order to make the plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to discover the outlier values on LAT, LONG

   - your plot is one way, but here's an automated way
2. First, use [`dat.info()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.info.html) to see which columns are numeric, what the dtypes are. You are interested in `LAT`, `LONG`.
3. **Use [`dat[['LAT','LONG']].describe()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) on your two columns of interest to get descriptive statistics and find out their outlier values.**

- `.describe()` takes an argument `percentiles` which is a list, it defaults to
  `[.25, .5, .75]`, which returns the 25th, 50th, and 75th percentiles.
- ..but you want to exclude rare/outlier values, so **try including (say) the 1st/99th and 5th/95th percentiles** also:

```
>>> pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}'.format  # suppress unwanted dp's
>>> dat[['LAT','LONG']].describe(percentiles=[.01,.05,.1,.25,.5,.9,.95,.99])
# OR:
>>> dat[dat['LAT'].between(33.97,36.96) & dat['LONG'].between(-101.80,-95.48)]

           LAT     LONG
count 11125.00 11125.00
mean     35.21   -96.85
std       2.69     7.58
min       0.00  -203.63
1%       33.97  -101.80  # <---- 1st percentile
5%       34.20   -99.76
10%      34.29   -98.25
25%      34.44   -97.63
50%      35.15   -97.37
90%      36.78   -95.95
95%      36.85   -95.74
99%      36.96   -95.48  # <---- 99th percentile
max      73.99    97.70
```

So the 1st-99th percentile ranges of your LAT and LONG values are:

```
  33.97 <= LAT  <=  36.96
-101.80 <= LONG <= -95.48
```

4. So now you can exclude these with a one-line `apply(..., axis=1)`:

```
    dat2 = dat[ dat.apply(lambda row: (33.97<=row['LAT']<= 36.96) and (-101.80<=row['LONG']<=-95.48), axis=1) ]

                   API#                                Operator  Operator ID WellType  ...                                   ZONE Unnamed: 18  Unnamed: 19 Unnamed: 20
    0     3500300026.00                   PHOENIX PETROCORP INC     19499.00       2R  ...                               CHEROKEE         NaN          NaN         NaN
    ...             ...                                     ...          ...      ...  ...                                    ...         ...          ...         ...
    11121 3515323507.00  SANDRIDGE EXPLORATION & PRODUCTION LLC     22281.00       2D  ...                    MUSSELLEM, OKLAHOMA         NaN          NaN         NaN
    
    [10760 rows x 21 columns]
```

Note this has gone from 11125 down to 10760 rows. So we dropped 365 rows.

Finally it's always a good idea to check that the extreme values of your filtered `LAT, LONG` are in the range you expected:

```
>>> dat2[['LAT','LONG']].describe(percentiles=[.01,.05,.1,.25,.5,.9,.95,.99])
           LAT     LONG
count 10760.00 10760.00
mean     35.33   -97.25
std       0.91     1.11
min      33.97  -101.76
1%       34.08  -101.62
5%       34.21   -99.19
10%      34.30   -98.20
25%      34.44   -97.62
50%      35.13   -97.36
90%      36.77   -95.99
95%      36.83   -95.80
99%      36.93   -95.56
max      36.96   -95.49
```

PS there's nothing magical about taking 1st/99th percentiles. You can play with the `describe(... percentiles)` yourself. You could use 0.005, 0.002, 0.001 percentiles etc. - you get to decide what constitutes an outlier.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Boolean series by comparing a column of a dataframe to a single value. Then you can use that series to index the dataframe, so that only those rows that meet the condition are selected:

```py
data = df[['LONG', 'LAT']]
data = data[data['LONG'] < -75]
```